# How to float a grid next another grid

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to place a grid next the grid which is clicked by user.
Every thing works fine but the next grid is not floating to the empty space automatically how to achieve that. 
Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="gridWrapper">
  <li class="grid">

  </li>
  <li class="grid">

  </li>
  <li class="grid">

  </li>

  <li class="grid">

  </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.gridWrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
.grid-full{
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

Script is here:

```
$('.grid').click(function() {
$('.grid-full').remove();
  $(this).after('<li class="grid grid-full"></li>');
});
```

[**My JSFiddle Link**:](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/cff6vmvp/1/)

[image]

Comment: I am really curious to know why you gave a `<br />` when starting the post?

Comment: It seems, that problem with your width settings. Cause you just can't place element with width:100% floating to another.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width: 100%` from the CSS:

```
.grid-full{
  background: red;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/haom8brd/**

According to comments, yes, you can. Find the next even grid and place it next:

```
$('.grid').click(function() {
  $('.grid-full').remove();
  $(this).next(".grid:nth-child(even)").after('<li class="grid grid-full"></li>');
});
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3sLhfL9e/**

Comment: I want that new grid should take 100% width.

Comment: @SureshPattu If the new grid needs to take 100%, then there would be no space, so it goes down. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add one grid with the width of 100% next to the clicked grid

Comment: I want the next grid should go and sit in the empty space

Comment: Yes, when you add a big box next to the empty space, which is half sized, it obviously goes down right?

Comment: Praveen I want all the grid should float relatively such way there shouldn't be a empty space on the container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98691/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-suresh-pattu).

Comment: Please check your answer again on clicking on the last element new grid is not added